# Open Google Maps from iPhone and show route

Tags: iphone

I was wondering how I can open Google Maps from my iphone app so that Google Maps shows the route when you arrive at the web page?

Today I use code that **only** shows the coordinate.

```
        NSString *latlong = [NSString stringWithString: @"59.33267,18.07361"];
        NSURL *url = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=%@", [latlong stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ]] autorelease];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Shows the route when you arrive at the web page?

Comment: Yeah, at the Google Maps web page/app.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the following format for url (you must specify both route start and endpoint):

```
"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%f,%f&saddr=%f,%f"
```