# how to connect or open another aplication with xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, iphone-4

now.. I was making a program.. but I want to make the program connected to another application or make an application running in my application.. such as, when people want to sign up to my application, I want to open safari application or make it running in my application? how can I do so? is there anyone help me with a sample code?

Or for example, in yelp, clicking some button will open google map application and point direction from our location to the next

how would I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your platform.  For OSX, `NSAppleScript` is your solution.  It allows you to interact with other scriptable programs like Safari, iTunes, Finder, etc.

For iPhone, your question has been asked / answered before: [Open Google Maps from iPhone and show route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760972/open-google-maps-from-iphone-and-show-route)

Comment: That one will show google map on safary. I want to launch the real google map

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a generic way to launch **any** app on iOS, there is no way to do it (at least using the official APIs).

It is possible, however, to launch a few apps based on their supported URL schemes.

To do this, you would do something like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

This will allow you to open a few native apps like Safari, Mail, Maps, Messages, App Store, etc (and depending on the URL, it may not only open the app but also perform some app-specific action).

There are a few repositories that list both native and third-party apps and their known URL schemes, such as these:

- http://handleopenurl.com/scheme
- http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes