# pass location parameters to registered location services application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps, core-location

I need to add the following feature to my iphone application.

When user taps a button I need to show a list of applications that work with maps/navigation/location (that can show him how to get from his current location to the destination point). When user chooses any application from this list my applicationn sends parameters (destination point) to it and opens it.

for example. user presses a button an then he sees the list of registered location services applications:
- google maps application
- navigate application
- iGo application
- some other application's

then user chooses "google maps application", for example. Then my application have to open google maps application with the parameters (destination point) passed to it.
So user can see the path (how to get) from his current location to the destination point inside google maps application

It could be done for android, what about iphone?

Comment: Probably duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760972/open-google-maps-from-iphone-and-show-route ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, It could not be done normally on ios